# Best way to use a base class's private member variable in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I have the following code, where a base class defines a pure virtual function, and the derived class defines this pure virtual function to perform some computations with base class's private member variable `var` (`var` won't be altered however). `var` is usually some large structure.

From a design perspective, I was reading that generally it is frowned upon to make `var` a protected member in this case. Would the best way to achieve what I want is to just pass `var` as an argument into `virtual_func()`?

This inspired a second question. What if I wanted to modify `var` in `virtual_func`? Would this change your answer?

```
class base
{
public:
  void search()
  {
    //virtual func in derived class must use var in base class, but not change var

    virtual_func();
  }

private:
  T var;
  virtual void virtual_func() = 0;
};

class derived : public base
{
  void virtual_func()
  {
    //does something with base class's var, but not alter it
  }
};
```

Comment: If you want to modify `var` then `protected` is your choice, I don't see why you wouldn't want to use it. I mean, when would you need to use that keyword otherwise? Because it looks like you're refusing to use it in the specific scenario it has been designed for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/index.html), in his book [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html) discusses `protected` in Section 13.9.

It was added precisely for your use case: to allow derived classes to access base class members, without exposing those members to everybody, or abusing `friend` declarations.  Five years later, the person (project) that made the request banned the use of protected member variables because they became a source of bugs and complicated maintenance.  He concludes by saying that protected data wasn't such a good idea, but protected member functions are fine.

Following those guidelines, you should leave all your base class data `private`, and add `protected` getter and setter functions to access the data.

Depending on your use case, and how expensive the data is to copy, your getter can either return a copy of the data or a reference (or const reference) to it.  Returning a non-const reference would allow you to modify the data directly via assignment (`getVar() = newvar;`), or to modify specific data members of the class.  Returning a const reference, and using a setter function, would encapsulate the data a bit more without overly exposing the class.  The setter function would also allow you more control over changes to `var`, including doing any validation that may be required.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to make `var` `protected` in the base class, you can add a `public` or `protected` getter function in the base that you can then call in the derived class.
Something like

```
T getVar() const { return var; }
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's another option. I do want to make `var` protected. That'd make my life really easy, but I've seen some resources state that it's bad practice. Any opinion on this?

Comment: @Iamanon If you need to read and modify `var` in derived classes but don't want others outside the inheritance hierarchy to access it, then I'd say that's the perfect use case for a `protected` member variable.

Comment: In your answer, `getVar()` is making a copy of `var`, which is apparently a large structure as per the Qn. It should be returned via `const T&` usually.

Comment: @iammilind I said "Something like". Whether or not returning by (`const`) reference or value makes sense here I leave up to OP.

Answer (score 1):

> *"From a design perspective, I was reading that generally it is frowned upon to make var a protected member in this case."*

Seems to be a wrong notion from wherever are you reading. If you have to access `base::var` in `class derived` then the **best design decision is to make `var` as `protected`**. Everything else will disturb the encapsulation. What else is the use case of `protected` other than the requirement mentioned in your question. :-)